# How to display the data in multiple list items in listview using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, json, listview

I'm getting the database data using php file. When i'm loading that php file using jquery that data will display in the same list item in listview. I have multiple titles but its displaying in the single list item. When i'm using `$.each` its showing error in `jquery-1.9.1.min.js` file  where i did wrong. Error as : TypeError:invalid 'in' operand e .

js code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "index.php",
    datatype: "jsonp",
    success: function(json) {
        $.each(json, function(i, data) {
    $("#section_list").append('<li><a href="#" id="'+ i +'"><h2>' + data.Subject + ' </h2></a></li>');
        });
    $("#section_list").listview('refresh');
}
});
```

php code :

```
<?php
    class db extends SQLite3
    {
        function __construct() {

            $this -> open('database.db');
        }
    }

    $db = new db();
    if (!$db) {
        echo $db-> lastErrorMsg();

    }
    else
    {
    }

    $sql =<<<EOF
      SELECT distinct(Subject,Category) from Data;
EOF;

$ret = $db->query($sql);

while($row = $ret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC) ){
      echo $row['Subject'] ."<br />";

   }

  $db->close();
?>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: jsFiddle code sample would be useful.

Comment: i updated with my php code

Answer (score 0):

i guess each won't work with a json object...try this:

```
$.each($.parseJSON(json), function(i, data) {
    //your code here
}
```

...tough i don't think your php is giving out json...if it's just a string try

```
var split = json.split("<br />");

$.each(split, function(i, data) {
    //your code here
}
```

...if you're not sure about that, do `console.log(json)`

Comment: because the each function crashes. can you post what's in data? is it a object? is it a string?

Comment: "Agano Jipya - New TestamentAgano la kale - Old Testament " ..this is the data what i want to display in listview.

Comment: is that exacly the output? if yes, use the second method in my answer....just replace `"<br />"` to `" - "`

Comment: i think in place of $parseJSON is $.parseJSON

Comment: yea..the parseJSON() on the split was nonsense

Comment: when i'm using second method in your answer getting this error SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character

Comment: getting all data in single listitem in listview